# Same code have different results

Tags: android

Situation 1

```
public void decrement(View view)
{
    quantity = quantity -1;
    TextView t1 = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.quant1));
    t1.setText(""+quantity);
}
```

Situation 2

```
public void decrement(View view)
{
    quantity = quantity -1;
    displayMessage(quantity);
}
public void displayMessage(int qty)
{
    TextView t1 = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.quant1));
    t1.setText(""+qty);
}
```

Why does the first 1 shows an error and the 2nd one dosn't they `enter code here`are basically the same code

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: It should work. Its look the same. please add the error you got

Answer (score 0):

Please include the error and how you are calling the methods.  Both methods execute identically for me, without error.  It may be something to do with your parameter.

Here's what I called:

```
int quantity = 0;

public void test(){
    decrement2(null);
    decrement(null);
}

public void decrement(View view)
{
    quantity = quantity -1;
    TextView t1 = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.quant1));
    t1.setText(""+quantity);
}

public void decrement2(View view)
{
    quantity = quantity -1;
    displayMessage(quantity);
}
public void displayMessage(int qty)
{
    TextView t1 = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.quant1));
    t1.setText(""+qty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Situation 1

```
public void decrement()
{
    quantity = quantity -1;
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quant1);
    t1.setText(""+quantity);
}
```

Situation 2

```
public void decrement()
{
    quantity = quantity -1;
    displayMessage(quantity);
}
public void displayMessage(int qty)
{
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quant1);
    t1.setText(""+qty);
}
```

Also add:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle sis){
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutid);

}
```

Othervise the findViewById will not work propperly.